# Could Springfox generate different definitions for same class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I've been using Springfox-swagger2:2.3.2 and Springfox-swagger-ui:2.3.1 in one of my projects and I've run into an issue.

The project is in Spring Boot 4.2.4 with JSON HAL standard.

Basically we use the same resource class for a POST body and the response body. Since it is HAL, this resource has links and embedded fields. In the POST definition we don't want the links and the embedded fields, but they should be there in the response definition.

Is it possible for Springfox to generate different definitions of this resource so that the POST Model Schema does not contain the links and embbeded fields?
I didn't want to have to create different classes of the same resource for each context that it is used. I've tried using the 'hidden' attribute in the @ApiModelProperty annotation, but that ended up removing the links and embedded fields from the response Model Schema.